# Scala: Sort a ListBuffer of (Int, Int, Int) by the third value most efficiently

Tags: scala, sorting, listbuffer

I am looking to sort a `ListBuffer(Int, Int, Int)` by the third value most efficiently. This is what I currently have. I am using `sortBy`. Note `y` and `z` are both `ListBuffer[(Int, Int, Int)]`, which I am taking the difference first. My goal is to optimize this and do this operation (taking the difference between the two lists and sorting by the third element) most efficiently. I am assuming the `diff` part cannot be optimized but the sortBy can, so I am looking for a efficient way to do to the sorting part. I found posts on sorting Arrays but I am working with ListBuffer and converting to an Array adds overhead, so I rather not to convert my ListBuffer.

```
val x = (y diff z).sortBy(i => i._3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** If you want to use Scala libraries then you can't do much better than that. Scala already tries to sort your collection in the most efficient way possible.
`SeqLike` defines `def sortBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Repr = sorted(ord on f)` which calls this implementation:

```
  def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Repr = {
    val len = this.length
    val arr = new ArraySeq[A](len)
    var i = 0
    for (x <- this.seq) {
      arr(i) = x
      i += 1
    }
    java.util.Arrays.sort(arr.array, ord.asInstanceOf[Ordering[Object]])
    val b = newBuilder
    b.sizeHint(len)
    for (x <- arr) b += x
    b.result
  }
```

This is what your code will be calling. As you can see it already uses arrays to sort data in place. According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) of `public static void sort(Object[] a)`:

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive,
>   iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons
>   when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the
>   performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is
>   randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the
>   implementation requires approximately n comparisons.

**2)** If you try to optimize by inserting results of your diff directly into a sorted structure like a binary tree as you produce them element by element, you'll still be paying the same price: average cost of insertion is `log(n)` times `n` elements `= n log(n)` - same as any fast sorting algorithm like merge sort.

**3)** Thus you can't optimize this case generically unless you optimize to your particular use-case.

**3a)** For instance, `ListBuffer` might be replaced with a `Set` and `diff` should be much faster. In fact it's implemented as:

```
 def diff(that: GenSet[A]): This = this -- that
```

which uses `-` which in turn should be faster than `diff` on `Seq` which has to build a map first:

```
def diff[B >: A](that: GenSeq[B]): Repr = {
    val occ = occCounts(that.seq)
    val b = newBuilder
    for (x <- this)
      if (occ(x) == 0) b += x
      else occ(x) -= 1
    b.result
  }
```

**3b)** You can also avoid sorting by using `_3` as an index in an array. If you insert using that index your array will be sorted. This will only work if your data is dense enough or you are happy to deal with sparse array afterwards. One index might also have multiple values mapping to it, you'll have to deal with it as well. Effectively you are building a sorted map. You can use a `Map` for that as well, but a `HashMap` won't be sorted and a `TreeMap` will require `log(n)` for add operation again.

Consult [Scala Collections Performance Characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) to understand what you can gain based on your case.

**4)** Anyhow, sort is really fast on modern computers. Do some benchmarking to make sure you are not prematurely optimizing it.

To summarize complexity for different scenarios...

Your current case:

- diff for `SeqLike`: `n` to create a map from `that` + `n` to iterate over `this` (map lookup is effectively constant time (C)) = `2n` or `O(n)`
- sort - `O(n log(n))`
- total = `O(n) + O(n log(n))` = `O(n log(n))`, more precisely: `2n + nlog(n)`

If you use `Set` instead of `SeqLike`:

- diff for `Set`: `n` to iterate (lookup is C) = `O(n)`
- sort - same
- total - same: `O(n) + O(n log(n))` = `O(n log(n))`, more precisely: `n + nlog(n)`

If you use `Set` and array to insert:

- diff - same as for Set
- sort - 0 - array is sorted by construction
- total: `O(n) + O(0)` = `O(n)`, more precisely: `n`. Might not be very practical for sparse data.

Looks like in the grand scheme of things it does not matter that much unless you have a unique case that benefits from last option (array).

If you would have a `ListBuffer[Int]` rather than `ListBuffer[(Int, Int, Int)]` I would suggest to sort both collections first and then do a diff by doing a single pass through both of them at the same time. This would be `O(nlog(n))`. In your case a sort by `_3` is not sufficient to guarantee exact order in both collections. You can sort by all three fields of a tuple but that will change the original ordering. If you are fine with that and writing your own diff then it might be the fastest option.